# Difference in size (Indesign Export)

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

Really 'noob' question maybe, but how come I have an InDesign document with exactly 85x200cm but when I export it the pdf gets a size of slightly less?

[image: Size on Document Setup]

[image: Size on PDF Exported]

Comment: Hi Joana, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!